# How can I replace all the spaces between words with point in a data frame in r?

Tags: r

I have a data frame, like this:

```
my.tree <- data.frame(Tree=c("Acer campestre", "Abies alba", "Pyrus communis", "Robinia pseudoacacia", "Tilia cordata"), 
                      Freq=c(23,65,47,69,65))
```

I want to replace all the `spaces` between words with `point` at once. I want to create new `data frame` (or modify this `data frame`) where there will be points between words of tree's name, e.g. `Acer.campestre`, `Abies.alba`, `Pyrus.communis` etc.

Is it possible to replace at once or how can I do these change easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
my.tree$Tree <- gsub(pattern = " ", replacement = ".", x = my.tree$Tree)

> my.tree
#                  Tree Freq
#1       Acer.campestre   23
#2           Abies.alba   65
#3       Pyrus.communis   47
#4 Robinia.pseudoacacia   69
#5        Tilia.cordata   65
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
> library(dplyr); mutate(my.tree, Tree = gsub(" ", ".", Tree))

#                  Tree Freq
#1       Acer.campestre   23
#2           Abies.alba   65
#3       Pyrus.communis   47
#4 Robinia.pseudoacacia   69
#5        Tilia.cordata   65
```

Answer (score 3):

It might be safer (and more conventional) to use `gsub`, but you could also use `make.names`:

```
make.names(my.tree$Tree)
# [1] "Acer.campestre"       "Abies.alba"           "Pyrus.communis"      
# [4] "Robinia.pseudoacacia" "Tilia.cordata"
```

Or even `chartr`:

```
chartr(" ", ".", my.tree$Tree)
# [1] "Acer.campestre"       "Abies.alba"           "Pyrus.communis"      
# [4] "Robinia.pseudoacacia" "Tilia.cordata"
```